Powershell + WPF - TreeListView hierarchical checkboxes
I have a problem. I need to create dynamicly created TreeListView with checkboxes. I already have that, but what i need to do, is automaticly select all children nodes, when parent is selected. How can i do that? This is my code i created already
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="My TreeView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="MyTreeView" Margin="10">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

# Define the data structure for the treeview
class Node {
    [string]$Name
    [System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Node]]$Children
    [bool]$IsChecked
}

# Populate treeview with sample data
$root = New-Object Node
$root.Name = "Root"
$root.Children = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Node]

$child1 = New-Object Node
$child1.Name = "Child 1"
$child1.Children = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Node]

$child2 = New-Object Node
$child2.Name = "Child 2"
$child2.Children = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Node]

$root.Children.Add($child1)
$root.Children.Add($child2)

$treeview = $window.FindName("MyTreeView")

$treeview.ItemsSource = @($root)

$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null



I could not get this to work without adding Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework.


How can i do that?

Add some logic to the setter of the IsChecked property that sets the corresponding property of all items in Children collection, and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify the view:
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged  {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Children { get; set; }

        private bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                foreach (var node in Children)
                  node.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
"@


I modify my code and use your solution but i need to change one thing node.IsChecked must be set to value not true because it won't work when unchecked. But i have another problem. I fill my tree view from xml. And its multiple nested. When i select node, and this node has children, it will select all nodes till first node with children occur.
before select:

after selecting root:

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="My TreeView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="MyTreeView" Margin="10">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

# Define the data structure for the treeview

Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged  {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Children { get; set; }

        private bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                foreach (var node in Children)
                  node.IsChecked = value;
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
"@

$root = New-Object Node
$root.Name = "Root"
$root.Children = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Node]

function TreeView-AddValuesFromXml {
    param($XmlNodes, $ParentItem)

    foreach ($Node in $XmlNodes.ChildNodes) {

        $Item = New-Object Node
        $Item.Name = "$($Node.GetAttribute("ID")) - $($Node.GetAttribute("Name"))"
        $Item.Children = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Node]

        $ParentItem.Children.Add($Item)

        if ($Node.HasChildNodes) {
            TreeView-AddValuesFromXml -XmlNodes $Node -ParentItem $Item 
        } 
    }
}

$TreeView = $Window.FindName("TreeView")

$XmlPath = "\\path_toXML"
$Xml = [xml](Get-Content $XmlPath)

# Populate TreeView with XML data
TreeView-AddValuesFromXml -XmlNodes $Xml.DocumentElement -ParentItem $root

$treeview = $window.FindName("MyTreeView")
$treeview.ItemsSource = @($root)
$root.add_PropertyChanged({
    
 })

$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

EDIT:
Problem Solved. I add
$Item.add_PropertyChanged({
})

after
$ParentItem.Children.Add($Item)
